# Spring Data JPA delete native query throwing exception

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I have a `User` entity and a `Role` entity. The relationship is defined like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="USER_ROLES", inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID"))
private List<Role> roles = null;
```

Now, when I delete a role, I need to delete the role from all the users that have that role. Normally you'd do something like this by looking up all the users with this role, removing the role from the list, and saving the user. However, when there could be over a million users, I don't want to be looping over this many entities in the app. So, I'm wanting to use a native query to remove rows from the `USER_ROLES` join table. I tried adding this to my repository:

```
@Query(value="DELETE FROM user_roles WHERE role_id = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
public void deleteRoleFromUsersWithRole(Long roleId);
```

However, when I do this, I see the following in the logs:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-11-02 14:27:14.418--ClientSession(707349235)--Connection(2096606500)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main])--DELETE FROM user_roles WHERE role_id = ?
   bind => [1000110139999999953]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-11-02 14:27:14.478--ClientSession(707349235)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main])--SELECT 1
[EL Warning]: 2013-11-02 14:27:14.482--UnitOfWork(1795045370)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-4,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
Error Code: 0
Call: DELETE FROM user_roles WHERE role_id = ?
    bind => [1000110139999999953]
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="DELETE FROM user_roles WHERE role_id = ?")
```

I don't understand what `No results were returned by the query.` is saying. The record does get deleted from the database, but this exception is causing everything to blow up.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A method annotated with @Query executes a query in order to read from the database. Not to update the database. To do that, as [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.modifying-queries) indicated, you need to add the `@Modifying` annotation to the method:

> All the sections above describe how to declare queries to access a given entity or collection of entities. Of course you can add custom modifying behaviour by using facilities described in Section 1.3, “Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories”. As this approach is feasible for comprehensive custom functionality, you can achieve the execution of modifying queries that actually only need parameter binding by annotating the query method with @Modifying:
>
> Example 2.13. Declaring manipulating queries

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1 where u.lastname = ?2")
int setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);
```

> This will trigger the query annotated to the method as updating query instead of a selecting one.

Comment: Ah, I'm still pretty new to Spring Data and JPA. I guess I should spend more time in the docs. I should note that I also had to add the `@Transactional` annotation to get it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what does this int return here ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate--

Comment: Why this not support Delete statement ?

Answer (score 9):

use this two annotations

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Modifying
@Transactional
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything that isn't in the accepted answer and @dnc253 comment on it

Comment: would you please metion where should i use that annotation

Comment: it allows you to delegate the responsibility of managing transactions to the Spring framework. When a method annotated with @Transactional is invoked, Spring will automatically begin a transaction, commit it on success, or roll it back on an exception. This eliminates the need for manual transaction handling.

Comment: & you can define custom rollback rules using the @Transactional annotation. This allows you to specify under what conditions a transaction should be rolled back. For example, you can specify that a transaction should be rolled back if a specific exception is thrown

Comment: The @Transactional annotation integrates seamlessly with various data sources, such as relational databases, JMS, and JPA, allowing you to work with different persistence technologies in a consistent manner

Comment: I believe this has clarified things for you.